# Scope of Sony Audio API

Tags: domoticz, sony-audio-control-api

I have a very basic question. I’m interested by the Sony STR-DN1080 and I’d like to control it with the Sony Audio API (the only one which exists as far as I know) using my own home automation system (domoticz for instance). But I don’t understand if this API only allows to control the AVR for audio streams or if it is broader than that (configuring behavior of viedo streams as well)…

For instance, is it possible to use API to ask the STR-DN1080 to use the HDMI input 1 as video source and send the video stream to HDMI (ouput) n°2 (for beamer) instead of HDMI ouput n°1 (TV), while sending the audio stream (from HDMI input 1) to speakers handled by the AVR ?

And later on (after movie), set the AVR to play video from Hdmi input 1 to HDMI ouput n°1 (TV) instead of to HDMI output 2 (the beamer) and only use the TV for audio (ie no activation of speakers handled by AVR for audio) ?

Could anyone clarify if it can be done with the API ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is the information in [this documentation site](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/) helpful?

Comment: Actually this show all available features: https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/api-references/api-overview-2

Answer (score 0):

To control the current output HDMI 1, HDMI 2 or TV can be done via the Audio Control API ("setPlayContent"), the API is for controlling the receiver and most thing you can do via the the Music Center (Song pal) app you can do via this API.

The Sony's Audio Control API it self has only very limited support for streaming audio and there are no support for video.

To have more control over the audio streams DLNA or chrome-cast has to be used. The receiver has no video player built in so that has to be provided via an external source via hdmi.

My recommendation is to not to try use the Audio Control API for audio streams it is better to use DLNA (or chrome-cast) from the beginning ([some help to get started](https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/get-started/play-dlna-file)).

Comment: Hi. Thank you for these explanations. To make sure I understand properly: does it mean that the API allows configuring the inputs/outputs/volume (etc.) of the AVR to be used when using a stream. The audio streams must be controlled by connecting to a Chromecast receiver embedded on the AVR (how should I access it and control it ? is there a guide somewhere ?). And for video streaming, the only thing which can be done is using the API to "connect" an HDMI input of the AVR to an output, and then control the HDMI source via something controlling the source itself. Am I correct ?

Comment: Yes, I think you have understand properly. The API can control inputs, outputs, change volume/mute, choosing sound fields power on/off etc.

I don't know of any good demo/tutorials of how to control Chromecast, ther is a very basic for DLNA on https://developer.sony.com/develop/audio-control-api/ under tutorials.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification !